# From row echelon to reduced row echelon

Tags: matrices

How do I reduce the matrix 
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}\quad \text{to}\quad \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0& 0& 0\end{pmatrix}\quad ? $$
Is it possible?

Comment: if you did $C_3\leftarrow C_3-2C_1$, $C_3\leftarrow C_3-C_1$ and $C_2\leftarrow C_2-2C_1$ what will be the result?

Comment: It is not possible using elementary row operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible. It can only be

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&-1\\0&1&2\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

by using $R_1-2R_2 \rightarrow R_1$.